# I want set values to my html inputs via event emitter and when submitting the form the values are not binding . How solve the problem?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a reactive form and two input fields are changing values from an Eventemitter(Values of Latitude and longitude is coming from an event emitter (child component))

This is my child.component.ts  where I am emitting values to parent component ...

```
this.lat.emit(this.latitude.toString());
this.lon.emit(this.longitude.toString());
```

This is my parent.component.html   ...

```
 <ngx-map (lon)="getLon($event)" (lat)="getLat($event)" ></ngx-map>
```

This is my parent.component.ts where catch the emitted values

```
  lat;
  lon;

  getLat($event) {
    this.lat = $event;
  }
  getLon($event) {
    this.lon = $event;
  }
```

This is how I setup validations in parent.component.ts.

```
form = new FormGroup({
    ///
    latitude: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.nullValidator,
    ]),
    longitude: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.nullValidator,
    ])
    ///
```

This is my form code in parent.component.html..

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="create()">

            <input
              status="primary"
              placeholder="Longitude"
              formControlName="longitude"
              type="text"
              nbInput
              fullWidth
              [value]="lon"

            />
            <input
              status="'primary'"
              placeholder="Latitude"
              formControlName="latitude"
              type="text"
              nbInput
              fullWidth
              [value]="lat"
            />
     </form>
```

This is my .ts code...

```
create() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

What I was is to bind latitude and longitude in my form inputs with emitted values and print all the from fields values from create() method .

How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `patchValue` from reactive forms as follows:

```
getLat($event) {
    this.form.controls['latitude'].patchValue($event);
}
getLon($event) {
    this.form.controls['longitude'].patchValue($event);
}
```

check [this link](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value) for more details on how it works: